# React child components undefined in HOC after rerender

Tags: reactjs, preact

I want to crate higher order component, add some logic in 'componentDidMount' and then force it to update via "this.setState({});". But after setState({}) fired, next props (in render method) became an emty object `{}`, and `this.props.children` also become undefined.

```
const SomeComponet = props => (
    <div>{props.children}</div>
);

function connect(WrappedComponent) {
    return class Connect extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.setState({});
        }
        render() {
            console.log("children:", this.props.children)
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>;
        }
    };
}

const HOC = connect(SomeComponet);

export default () => (
    <HOC>
        <span>!!!!!!!!!</span>
    </HOC>
);
```

Why is that ?

In the console I see such output:

```
children: [VNode]
children: undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using the HOC? Don't see anything in what you have posted that would cause the behavior, so think it is higher up.

Comment: @TLadd, i updated original code. Please take a look.